# About gravitational time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

Your clock run slower than the clocks on Earth?

Comment: Welcome!  Other way around actually - clocks tick slower in a gravity field, or under acceleration.   So time on GPS satellites at high altitude away from the Earth increments faster than clocks on the Earth’s surface, and require adjustment so they stay synchronized.

Comment: A small correction: clocks tick slower based on *potential*, not acceleration. The two are very closely related for a gravitational field, so it's easy to confuse them, but in a uniformly accelerating reference frame the ticking of clocks is based on distance from the origin, even though all of them are accelerating at the same rate.

Answer (score 2):

Faster indeed. According to general relativity, an interval of time $\Delta t$ of an observer very far from the Earth (or any mass) is related to the interval of time measured by a steady observer closer to the planet $\Delta \tau$ following:
$$\Delta \tau=\left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)^{-1/2}\Delta t$$
Where $r$ is the distance from the planet to the close observer. This gives us that measured by an observer closer to the planet $\Delta \tau>\Delta t$ being greater and grater as the close observer gets even closer.
Note that, in relativity,  time is considered the fourth coordinate like space. That means, as space can be bent, time as well. This bending is caused by the planet as mass, or more generally, energy curves spacetime following the Einstein Field Equations.

Comment: The explanation above mixes the time intervals. $\Delta \tau$ is the time far from the planet (that is, the proper time) and $\Delta t$ is that within the gravitational field. The factor in brackets is less than 1 so that a process taking time $\Delta t$ in the field takes a smaller time $\Delta \tau$ in space - i.e time close to the planet is running slower so things take longer. Even [Wikipedia gets this wrong!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#) Weinberg derives this in his book on General Relativity -  "Gravitation and Cosmology".

Comment: You are right, I missed a minus sign in the exponent derived from Schwartzschild metric, that was a long time ago.